# GGplot not showing on RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am trying to plot data I have measuring the frequency of bigrams in . a document to a circular bar plot. However, I cannot see the actual plot when running the code on RStudio. I am not sure what I am doing wrong

This is the code I have

```
sona_dfm <- tokens(sona_corp) %>%
  tokens_remove("\\p{P}", valuetype ="regex", padding=TRUE)%>%
  tokens_remove("\\d+", padding = TRUE)%>%
  tokens_ngrams(n=3) %>%
  dfm()
#frequency table
freq_table <- textstat_frequency(sona_dfm, n=25) #top25

# Add lines to the initial dataset
freq_table$id=seq(1, nrow(freq_table))

# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data=freq_table
number_of_bar=nrow(label_data)
angle= 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
label_data$hjust<-ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle<-ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

# Make the plot
p = ggplot(freq_table, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=frequency)) +   
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=alpha("green", 0.3)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1500)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar(start = 0) + 
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=frequency+20, label=feature, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE )+
show(p)
```

This is the data i have
[data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1udVp0j8wF7WDG62rXLbFsai3HWibEZkJ_84UEZgpWN0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Remove the plus sign after `geom_text`. As simple as that. I am voting to close as off-topic/simple typo.

Comment: Even without the typo (+ sign after geom_text) there is still a problem and I cannot see the plot @RuiBarradas

Comment: I have downloaded the data and ran your code starting with the line `# Get the name and the y position of each label`. It worked after fixing the typo. Instead of `show` try `print(p)`.

Comment: `p` instead of `show(p)` will also work to show the plot.